# Inorder tree tranversal on binary search tree doesn't give the elements in order?

Tags: binary-trees, binary-search-trees

I have been told that inorder tree tranversal of binary search trees returns the tree elements in order. I came up with this binary search tree:

```
      20
    /
 10
    \
     26
```

However the inorder tree tranversal of this seems to be 10, 26, 20?! What is wrong here?

Comment: "I have been told that inorder tree tranversal", 
it should have been binary search tree.

Comment: @HIRAKMONDAL yes I meant to say that

Comment: In your "ASCII-art", is the root at the left or at the top?

Comment: (Could you decide on *traversal* rather than *transversal*?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a valid binary search tree, since 26 is greater than 20 and is in its left subtree.

Answer (score 1):

That is not correct BST as Narek mentioned. BST should be -

```
 20
/   \
10  26
```

For inorder traversal, start visiting tree from Top to bottom and left to right manner and print a node only when it is referenced 2nd time.

So, inorder traversal here would be 10,20,26.